# Advanced Object Identifying issue

Tags: java

Alright How do I make the above code executes correctly in an object oriented way so that if I create 3 different channels on my discord server and I want the channels locked only bot can send messages and in code each class `channel` will have a method after all types of data(embeded messages, images, text, more text, etc) are created

To execute this specific channel on so I can just create 3 different Class files for the 3 channels and make the code handle the entire process.
✔️
Example of a RuleChannel.class

```java
public class RulesChannel {

/…variabls…creation…of…String…jda.EmbdedMessage…/

@OverrideFromSuper
public void execute() {
     STRING_MESSAGE1.executeOrder(1);
      EMBDED_MESSAGE1.executeOrder(2);

STRING_MESSAGE2.executeOrder(3);
}

//So now i just need 2 more classes like this to make the job done
}
```

This was my attempt

I am working with the library [Java JDA Discord Bot](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA), and I am creating a Discord Bot API where it can automatically & fully handle a specific channel for the users in the Discord server (or Guild).

```
package com.rs.discord.embedHandler;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.rs.discord.RSDiscordBot;

import lombok.Getter;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.EmbedBuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.TextChannel;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.interactions.components.ActionRow;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.interactions.components.Button;

/**
 * Represents the abstract class of bot automatically handling an entire channel with plain, or embeded message
 *  with or without buttons in the embeded message.
 *
 *  <p>To use the code we create a new Class and extend this class to inherit and make good use of the built-in easy methods.
 *
 */

public abstract class HandledChannelBot {
    
    /**
     * The TextChannel ID identifier of the channel.
     */
    @Getter private TextChannel channelId;
    
    @Getter private List<String> messages;
    
    @Getter private List<File> files;
    
    /**
     * a Map<EmbedBuilder, ActionRow> that holds all the external embeded messages
     *  received from the desired channel
     */
    @Getter private Map<EmbedBuilder, ActionRow> embededs;
    
    /*
     * <p>This method is not to be called in a Concrete class.
     * 
     * Built-in method for initiating the map 
     */
    private void init() {
        if(embededs == null)
            embededs = new HashMap<EmbedBuilder, ActionRow>();
        if(messages == null)
            messages = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(files == null) {
            files = new ArrayList<File>();
        }
    }
    
    public void insertMessage(String message) {
        messages.add(message);
    }
    
    public void insertFile(File file) {
        files.add(file);
    }
    
    /** 
     * Call this method insert an Embeded message WITH reactive buttons 
     */
    public void insertEmbedWithButtons(EmbedBuilder eb, Button... buttons) {
        embededs.put(eb, ActionRow.of(buttons));
    }
    
    public void insertEmbedWithoutButtons(EmbedBuilder eb) {
        embededs.put(eb, null);
    }
    
    public HandledChannelBot(String channelId) {
        init();
        this.channelId = RSDiscordBot.getJda().getTextChannelById(channelId);
    }
    
    public void send() {
        //WIP
    }
}
```

This is a WIP abstract class that I am coding in order to be able to easily create instances of the abstract class and easily insert custom EmbededMessages, Buttons, Normal Messages, whatever TypeOjbect the developer needs.

The idea is that an instance concrete class can build an Object train of the desired objects listed below

```
embededs = new HashMap<EmbedBuilder, ActionRow>();
messages = new ArrayList<String>();
files = new ArrayList<File>();
```

What I am trying to do is to find a way to create a custom Object identifying a main ChannelContentData where it can either be

```
EmbededMessage em;
String message;
File file;
```

And the ChannelContentData to have a type and int indexOrder;

```
int indexOrder;

public enum Ob_Type {
        TEXT_MESSAGE, EMBEDED_MESSAGE_WITHOUT_BUTTONS, EMBED_MESSAGE_WITH_BUTTONS;
    }
```

- A Method/way to be added in the concrete class that after the ChannelContentData Objects created it can be set to be executed in a specific order for example:

```
//this is our concrete class
public class WelcomeChannelBot extends HandledChannelBot {


     public EmbedBuilder createEmbededMessage1() {
    EmbedBuilder eb = new EmbedBuilder();
    eb.appendDescription("Text 123");
    eb.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    return eb;
      }


    public EmbedBuilder createEmbededMessage2() {
    EmbedBuilder eb = new EmbedBuilder();
    eb.appendDescription("Text 123");
    eb.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    return eb;
      }

     @Override
     public void executeInOrder() {
        executableOrder.add(createEmbededMessage1()).executeInOrder(1);
        exectuableOrder.add(createembededMessage2()).executeInOrder(2);
      }
```

So the final use of the code can be a Class extending the Abstract class having the way passed to the VM so that the Bot can just execute the required data in the specific order in the channel.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was very simple :)

Simply, create a new class then add `MessageBuilder1();` `MessageBuilder2();` whatever you like.. a `String introMessage;`.. identify the `TextChannel jdaSender = jda.getTextChannelById(x);`

Then:

````java
public void execute() {
  /*1. Message*/jdaSender.sendMessage(introMessage)queue();
  /*2. Message*/jdaSender.sendMessage(MessageBuilder1().build).queue();
  /*3. Message*/jdaSender.sendMessage(MessageBuilder2().build.queue();
}```
````